# Make Date dynamic but keep Time static

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this query that I have to manually change the date daily but not the time.
Below you can see that I have 2014-12-11 the next day I have to change the date ONLY to 2014-12-12. Any ideas how to make this dynamic ?

```
UPDATE tblData SET Issued = '2014-12-11 08:00:00.000' 
  where issued < '2014-12-11 08:00:00.000' and called > '2014-12-11 08:00:01.000' 
  and tbldate = '2014-12-11'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Date DATE = '2014-12-11'  --<-- Date variable 

UPDATE tblData 
   SET Issued = CAST(@Date AS DATETIME) +  CAST('08:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
where issued < CAST(@Date AS DATETIME) + CAST('08:00:00.000' AS DATETIME)
  and called > CAST(@Date AS DATETIME) + CAST('08:00:01.000' AS DATETIME)
  and tbldate = @Date
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. For the first line to make it dynamic I used DECLARE @Date date = CAST(GETDATE() as date)

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use the DATEADD function here?

Demo:

```
DECLARE @TestData TABLE (Issued DATETIME);

INSERT INTO @TestData VALUES(DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()));

SELECT * FROM @TestData;

UPDATE @TestData
SET Issued = DATEADD(day, 1, Issued);

SELECT * FROM @TestData;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you update the data each day?  Just use a view or add a computed column to get what you want.  It would be something like this:

```
alter table
    add TodayIssued as dateadd(day,
                               datediff(day, Issued, getdate()),
                               Issued) ;
```

Comment: This is not dynamic the Date changes daily.

Comment: All dates have to be dynamic.

Comment: I have to update all the records daily if issued was before 8am and called after 8am with 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tblData
SET Issued =  concat(substring(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),105),1,10),' 08:00:00.000')  
where issued <  concat(substring(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),105),1,10),' 08:00:00.000' )
    AND
    called > concat(substring(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),105),1,10),' 08:00:01.000')
    and tbldate = substring(convert(varchar(10),getdate(),105),1,10)
```